# How to print numbers in ascending order. How can I do that without doing an array?

Tags: java

> Write an application that inputs three integers from the user and displays the sum, average, product, smallest and largest of the numbers. It also should print the three numbers in an ascending order (from smallest to the largest)
>
> Note: The calculation of the average in this exercise should NOT result in an integer representation of the average. So if the sum of the values is 7, the average should be 2.33, not 2. (Hint:  your average variable should be of type double and you should cast your average calculation that involves two integer numbers as double)

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner
import java.util.Arrays; 

//Assignment 1 
//Program that displays the sum, average, product, smallest and largest of three numbers,  

public class Main 
  {
    // main method begins execution of Java application
    public static void main (String[] args) 
 {  
    int a,b,c; 
    int cnt = 0;
    
    // create a Scanner to obtain input from the command window
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Please enter the first number : "); // prompt
    a = sc.nextInt(); // read the first number from user 
    
    System.out.print("Please enter the second number : "); // prompt
    b = sc.nextInt(); // read the second number from user 
    
    System.out.print("Please enter the third number : "); //prompt 
    c = sc.nextInt(); // read the third number from user 
    
    int sum;  // sum of a, b, and c 
    
    int max; // Maximum number  
    
    int min; // Minimum number
    
    int result; // product of numbers
 
    int average; // average of numbers
 
    max = a;
    min = c; 
    
    if (a < c)
        max = b; 
    
    if (c  > a)
        max = c;
        
    if (a < b)
        min = a; 
    
    sum = a  + b + c ; // add numbers, then score total in sum
    
    result = a * b * c; // calculate product of numbers
    
    average = a + b + c /3;  // calculate average of numbers
   
    System.out.println("The maximum number is : " + max); // display max
    
    System.out.println("The minimum number is : " + min); // display min
    
    System.out.println("The sum is : " + sum ); // display sum
    
    System.out.println("The product is : " + result); // display product 
 
    System.out.printf("The average is : %.2f%n", (double) (a + b + c )/3); // display average
    
    System.out.printf("And here are the numbers in ascending order : "); // displays the numbers in ascending order
}

}
```

Comment: Why don't you explain why you think you need an array in the first place? The assignment clearly states that your user is required to input three values, not *up to three* values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you want to avoid an array? If you treat your input as a collection of numbers and use any suitable data structure including arrays, your code will be able to handle different amount of numbers. Btw,  your current code will yield the wrong `max` and `min` values.